# too many redirects for wordpress on nginx with apache2

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

I have just installed wordpress on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Nginx acts as reverse proxy for apache2.

wp-admin is working fine, but I am unable to open the homepage.

Nginx Server Code:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html/testblog;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name testblog.com;

        location / {
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8182;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Apache Virtual Host Conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8182>
        ServerName testblog.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/testblog

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errortest.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/accesstest.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       ubuntu
127.0.1.1       testblog.com
```

I have all the wp files in the folder /var/www/html/testblog/.

> testblog.com/wp-admin: working fine.
>
> testblog.com: giving too many redirects.

[Here is my settings page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNfpN.png)

I guess my settings are correct. I have tried defining WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in wp-config.php, but no luck.

My /var/www/html/testblog/.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

> testblog.com/wp-admin: working.
>
> testblog.com: giving too many redirects error

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Edit:** I have already disabled all the plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Apache2 is running WordPress, you need to configure `nginx` to proxy everything. At the moment you have both `nginx` and Apache2 rewriting URIs to `/index.php`, and because `nginx` does it first, WordPress never sees the original URI.

Start with this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name testblog.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8182;
    }
}
```

And if you decide to allow some of the static URIs to be served by `nginx` fine. But you can't let `nginx` map URIs to `/index.php` because that will not work.

Comment: Dude that was the thing. Can you please explain, why wp-admin was okay but not the homepage. Feeling sorry, cannot vote this up.

Comment: One more thing, homepage (testblog.com) is opening fine. But when I click on a post say: http://testblog.com/sunny/ this says: 404 not found from Apache.

Comment: I'm guessing that `/wp-admin/index.php` doesn't generate a redirect like `/index.php`. Also, look [at this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Fixing_Other_Issues) regarding why Apache may not be handling pretty permalinks correctly.

Comment: It seems that you are correct regarding wp-admin/index.php. I figured out that my mod_rewrite was not enabled. After enabling it everything works fine. Thanks Richard for helping and giving your invaluable time.

Comment: Can you give an example, in which the wordpress installation is in a subfolder (e.g. /blog/)?? I am stuck with this for couple days now... I am using Docker, maybe you know something about that too.

Comment: Does it mean the Nginx will override the Wordpress `.htaccess`? What is the process for both reverse proxy?