# Wordpress stuck on "too many redirects"

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, apache2, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a wordpress website that uses nginx as a reverse proxy to apache - apache serves only php requests.
I was able to successfully install wordpress but whenever I try to open the website it says "too many redirects". However when I try to open example.com/wp-admin it loads and I am able to login into and access the admin panel.

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/webproxy is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_ip;

    location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

I checked both apache and nginx error logs - empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725314/too-many-redirects-for-wordpress-on-nginx-with-apache2

Comment: Please checkout this link "https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/fixing-redirects-error-wordpress/".